# View shell function's current definition

Tags: function, bashrc

So I am editing bashrc constantly, and I have a terminal open with a working function definition, although bashrc has been updated with a wrong function definition. (Because the definition do not change until I source the updated bashrc) How can I look up the working function definition in this case? For example, if I type:

```
alias function_name
```

I can see what the definition is for that alias. Is there a command similar for function? If not, is there a command to output entire bashrc that the current terminal is using?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
typeset -f function
```

displays the indicated function's current definition.
It works in ksh (where it originated), bash and zsh. (n.b. in zsh, `type -f`, `which`, `functions` and `whence -f` also show the function definition.)

Comment: You can also use `whence -cv` in zsh. The `-v` option is to tell you, if there is no such alias or function (or otherwise executable in you `PATH`) at all. If you use it a lot (as I), you could alias it to a one-word command.